# How to check collectionFS database?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Is there a similar way to check collectionFS database like mongoDB. For example I open the command line and go to the directory of the meteor project and type in meteor mongo. Then I just hit db.users.find(). What is the equivalent in collectionFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just for checking, why don't you use a collection browser, like [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/)?

Moreover, if I'm not wrong, gridFS (i.e. collectionFS) data should be query-able like any other mongoDB collection.